# mitmf doesn't work when disabled ip forward

Tags: wifi, man-in-the-middle, ip, kali-linux

- I have virtual machine windows connected to NAT network.
- I also have kali linux virtual machine connected to same NAT network.
- I have port forwarding disabled. `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`
  gives me 0.

I run the command : `mitmf --arp --spoof --gateway 10.0.2.1 --targets 10.0.2.4 -i eth0` . then I go to windows virtual machine type the url and it still accesses the website. Why? I know windows's virtual machine's ip is 10.0.2.4 so its requests have to come to kali linux machine first. I have ip forwarding disabled. so request doesn't go anywhere. why does it still work and accesses the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This still works because MITMf [automatically enables](https://github.com/byt3bl33d3r/MITMf/blob/067cc4e3370ec1a73aa7b761bf5b664ec5f77041/plugins/spoof.py#L79) IP forwarding when using the `--spoof` option:

> ```
> def set_ip_forwarding(value):
>     log.debug("Setting ip forwarding to {}".format(value))
>     with open('/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward', 'w') as file:
>         file.write(str(value))
>         file.close()
> ```

Comment: What should I do to disable it?

Comment: You could run without `--spoof` but then it's not a mitm, so I don't see what you are trying to achieve if you want to mitm your network but without ip forwarding?

Comment: The thing why I decided to ask this question is because I didn't understand this: when target makes request, it first comes to middle-man(hacker computer), then it forwards the request to the router.  Question 1) i didn't specify that target's mac_address for router has to change to my mac_address, i only specify router's mac address to change to my mac_address for target., but not vica verca. so what will happen after router returns response? does router return response to hacker or target without middleman?

Comment: what do you think? When i was using arspoof command, i'd run two commands. but now with mitmf, i can only run one command.

Comment: The router returns the response to the man in the middle. I would recommend further reading on the ARP protocol and [how ARP-based MITM works](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/153328/147932) to ensure you fully understand how the attack works

Comment: how does this work? i didn't run the command to change router's arp table for target's ip's mac address to my(hacker's) mac_address. does that command I specifed in the question do the both automatically?

Comment: That's my question. I know how it works. just curious one command does change router's mac address to hacker's mac address and also target-s mac adress to hacker's mac address?

Comment: Yes, MITMf also does all this with the [`--arp`](https://github.com/byt3bl33d3r/MITMf/blob/067cc4e3370ec1a73aa7b761bf5b664ec5f77041/core/poisoners/ARP.py) option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90802/discussion-between-nika-khurashvili-and-joe).